# SVN Merge/Revert between branches for large team

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have following scenario.

Many team members are working in Team in branch name called "dev" and we have another branch called "QA".

### Case 1

1. Developoer1 is committed on revision 20 of dev branch.
2. Developoer2 is committed on revision 21 of dev branch.
3. Developoer3 is committed on revision 23 of dev branch.

Now, developer2 committed his code for QA so, want to do svn merge with 21 in QA branch But, not doing due to that have the code of developer1 with him which is committed in svn 20.

### Case 2

1. Developoer1 is committed on revision 20 of dev branch.
2. Developoer2 is committed on revision 21 of dev branch.
3. Developoer3 is committed on revision 23 of dev branch.
4. Developer1 committed (Revision: 20) code for QA and merge into the branch. Next Developer2 committed (Revision: 21) code for QA and merge into the branch. Moving forward Developer3 committed (Revision: 22) code for QA and merge into the branch.

Now, if Developer2 code is getting QA Fail then how can we revert all the code from QA branch.

If you need more clarity in above case then let me know so, I can give you more clarity and cases on above.

So, Please guide me on above case how can I solve these problems.

I am happy to move in GIT as well if there is a solution with GIT.

Comment: How long lived are the branches? How much code is in them? Also, not sure why you put the git tag when you're using svn.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with SVN. What have you tried?

Comment: @NimrodArgov : I am happy to move in GIT if above cases are fulfilled via GIT. Also, My branches are running since 6 months with more than 30 developers are working on it and code size depends upon tasks.

Comment: @bahrep : Please share the steps how we can solve the problem via GIT/SVN

Comment: @JigarChaudhary I would recommend that you read documentation. Neither Git nor SVN will magically design a branching strategy for you. You should learn the tools that you work with.